# Unknown drupal_view() function although Twig Tweak is installed

Tags: 8, theming, acquia-cloud

Acquia BLT won't let me commit some Twig.

```
> tests:twig:lint:all
Validating twig syntax for all custom modules and themes...
Iterating over fileset files.twig...
  ERROR  in ~/repos/agency/client-site/docroot/themes/custom/client_theme/templates/taxonomy/taxonomy-term--faq.html.twig (line 35)
      33       {{ title_suffix }}
      34       <div class="accordion" data-accordion>
  >>  35         {{ drupal_view('faqs_per_term', 'block_1', term.id) }}
  >> Unknown "drupal_view" function. 
      36       </div>
      37     </div>
 [WARNING] 28 Twig files have valid syntax and 1 contain errors.
```

I have installed and enabled Twig Tweak module, and rebuilt cache.

Do you know of any reason why BLT might not know the module is installed?

Possibly relevant: I'm running Drupal and BLT under Lando. The error is triggered after `git push` but I get the same result if I call `lando blt tests:twig:lint:all` directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/acquia/blt/issues/2815

Comment: Works like a charm! If you make an answer out of it, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a module defines new twig filters or functions, they need to be manually excluded from the blt linter. Per [a comment in the BLT issue queue](https://github.com/acquia/blt/issues/2815#issuecomment-388392150), you can make these exclusions in *blt.yml* like:

```
validate:
  twig:
    functions:
      - drupal_block
      - drupal_field
      - drupal_view
      - drupal_region
      - drupal_entity
      - drupal_field
      - drupal_menu
      - drupal_form
      - drupal_image
      - drupal_token
      - drupal_config
      - drupal_title
      - drupal_url
      - drupal_link
      - drupal_messages
      - drupal_breadcrumb
```

This is also documented in the [Overriding variables at runtime](https://docs.acquia.com/blt/extending-blt/#overriding-variables-at-runtime) section of the blt docs (it's near the bottom of the section, under the *tests:* list item).